# How can I convert this JS function to TS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I came across [this](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#SmartFormComponent) JS function in react-hook-form docs:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Form({ defaultValues, children, onSubmit }) {
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const { handleSubmit } = methods;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return child.props.name
          ? React.createElement(child.type, {
              ...{
                ...child.props,
                register: methods.register,
                key: child.props.name
              }
            })
          : child;
       })}
    </form>
  );
}
```

I want to convert it to TS. I tried following:

```
import React, {ReactNode} from "react";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface RhfFormProps {
  defaultValues?: {}; 
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<{}>;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export default function Form({ defaultValues, children, onSubmit }: RhfFormProps) {
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const { handleSubmit } = methods;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return child.props.name
          ? React.createElement(child.type, {
              ...{
                ...child.props,
                register: methods.register,
                key: child.props.name,
              },
            })
          : child;
      })}
    </form>
  );
}
```

But it gives following errors:

1. For `child` variable:

   ```
   Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
   ```
2. For `props` variable:

   ```
   Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal'.
   ```

Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.

How do I do this?

**Update**

As suggested in answer by Noah, I tried to introduce generics:

```
interface RhfFormProps<T> {
  defaultValues?: T; 
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<T>;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export default function Form<T>({ defaultValues, children, onSubmit }: RhfFormProps<T>) {
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const { handleSubmit } = methods;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return child.props.name
          ? React.createElement(child.type, {
              ...{
                ...child.props,
                register: methods.register,
                key: child.props.name,
              },
            })
          : child;
      })}
    </form>
  );
}
```

However, I still get some errors:

1. On `defaultValues`:

   ```
   Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'UnpackNestedValue<DeepPartial<T>>'.
   ```
2. Original error on `child.props` is not eliminated:

   ```
   Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal'.
   ```
3. Error on `child.type`:

   ```
   Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal'.
   ```
4. 

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use `{}` as a Type
2. For child you have to do something like
   `if (!child) return <p>Error</p>, else return <your code/>`
3. For props do not write out every parameter, try it like this:

```
interface RhfFormProps {
  defaultValues?: {}; 
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<{}>;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export default function Form(props: RhfFormProps) {
    ...yourCode
}
```

4. I think you should google for Typescript Generics

Comment: **Q1.** By 4th point, do you suggest to introduce generics for `defaultValues` and `SubmitHandler` as shown in the update done at the end of OP **Q2.** By 2nd point, do you mean to replace `{ defaultValues, children, onSubmit }` with `props` and then refer as `props.defaultValues`, `props.children` and `props.onSubmit`?

Comment: You don't have to define your props Attributes twice you already do this in the Interface. Also I took a look at the children.map function and I think "child"  just doesn't have a "props" attribute, thats why u get this error. Also at some point you have to pass a type into the Generic (T). May take a look at https://react-hook-form.com/ts

Comment: "child just doesnt have props attribute" - isnt `props` a [default react component input](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)? Also if `child.props` isnt there, then how the example I quoted at the beginning of OP can be there in react-hook-form docs? ([link](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#SmartFormComponent))

Comment: I think only if u use the Class syntax. For the Function syntax props are just usual function parameters.